# MariaDB Master-Slave replication don't work without error

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-replication

I have two MariaDB 10.1.16 server on two different host.
I setup a Master-Slave replica and there aren't errors:

SLAVE:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: host02
                  Master_User: slave
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 10
              Master_Log_File: host02-bin.000012
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 3814
               Relay_Log_File: host03-relay-bin.000027
                Relay_Log_Pos: 3188
        Relay_Master_Log_File: host02-bin.000012
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: db1,db2,db3,db4,db5,db1,db2,db3,db4,db5
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 3814
              Relay_Log_Space: 3491
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 1
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
                   Using_Gtid: No
                  Gtid_IO_Pos:
      Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids:
  Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids:
                Parallel_Mode: conservative
```

MASTER:

```
MariaDB [(none)]>  SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+-----------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+ | File                  | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+-----------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+ | host03-bin.000012 |     3814 |              |                  |
+-----------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
```

No errors or warning on Alert log.

master my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
server_id=1
relay-log=host02-relay-bin
log-bin=host02-bin
```

slave my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
log-bin
server_id=2
replicate-do-db="db1,db2,db3,db4,db5"
relay-log=host03-relay-bin
log-bin=host03-bin
```

The problem is there isn't errors but changes made in MASTER (ex. INSERT) doesn't replicate on SLAVE.
Maybe Replicate_Do_DB problem?

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not have a database called `db1,db2,db3,db4,db5`.

Instead, have 5 `replicate-do-db` lines in the slave's my.cnf.

Also, be sure not to do this:

```
USE db88;
INSERT INTO db1.tbl ...
```

The `db88` will be used instead of `db1`, and the insert will be ignored.